# pdfmake page number and local variable access from inside footer function

Tags: angular, pdfmake

Having a problem figuring out a specific issue when generating a report using PDFMake. My project uses Angular 8 for context so this is inside a modal component. Code Below of a simple version I'm using for testing. How do I define this.orderNum while inside "footer: function (currentPage, pageCount)"?

```
@Component({
 selector: 'app-utilities-print-OrderPrintModal',
 templateUrl: './printtemplate.html'
})

export class OrderPrintModal implements OnInit {
  @Input() passedOrderNum: string;
  public orderNum: string;
  public pdf: any;

 ngOnInit() {   
   this.orderNum= this.passedOrderNum;
   this.print();
 }

 print() {
    var dd = {
      pageOrientation: "portrait",
      pageMargins: [20, 10, 20, 40],
      pageSize: "LETTER",
    
    footer: function (currentPage, pageCount) {
    var t = {
      layout: "noBorders",
      fontSize: 8,
      margin: [25, 0, 25, 0],
      table: {
        widths: ["*", "*"], 
        body: [
          [
            { text: "Page  " + currentPage.toString() + " of " + pageCount },
            { text: "orderNum  " + this.orderNum }
          ]
        ]
      }
    };

    return t;
  }
  this.createPDF(dd)       
 }

  createPDF(dd: any) {
     this.pdf = pdfMake.createPdf(dd);
     this.pdf.getDataUrl((dataUrl) => {
     const targetElement = document.querySelector('#iframeContainer');
     const iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
     iframe.src = dataUrl;
     iframe.setAttribute("style", "width:100%; height:100%;");
     targetElement.appendChild(iframe);
   });
 }      
}
```

Console error is : core.js:6014 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'orderNum' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'orderNum' of undefined

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `function` has it's own `this` property so when you say `this.orderNum` inside you're footer function, you're referring to the footer functions `this` and not your class `this`.

Change your footer function to an arrow function...

```js
print() {
  var dd = {
    pageOrientation: "portrait",
    pageMargins: [20, 10, 20, 40],
    pageSize: "LETTER",
    
    footer: (currentPage, pageCount) => {
      var t = {
        layout: "noBorders",
        fontSize: 8,
        margin: [25, 0, 25, 0],
        table: {
          widths: ["*", "*"], 
          body: [
            [
              { text: "Page  " + currentPage.toString() + " of " + pageCount },
              { text: "orderNum  " + this.orderNum }
            ]
          ]
        }
      };

      return t;
    }
    this.createPDF(dd)       
  }
}
```

Comment: This was perfect. Thanks